How can I create a symbolic link in Thunar?
In KDE Plasma's file manager "Dolphin" I can drag and drop a folder to any other location while holding down the Alt key in order to create a symbolic link to this folder in the other location, but if I do the same thing in Thunar it just copies the folder.
So tell me, how can I actually create a symbolic link with XFCE's file manager Thunar?

I found out that holding Ctrl + Shift while dragging and dropping files and folders in Thunar creates symbolic links instead of copies.
According to Thunar maintainer Alexander Schwinn's comment on a gitlab issue about this topic, there are even more ways to create symbolic links in Thunar:


Right-click DnD: Grab a file with the right mouse and move it into some folder. On mouse-button release, you will be asked if you want to
copy, move or create a symlink.
Select any number of files and press edit --> make link in the menu You can create a custom action for doing so.
Define a shortcut for the "make link" action in preferences --> shortcuts and use that"


